# How can the button below when you push the plus?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://dizievents.ch/inscription-food-n-liquor/)

Each time you press the "plus" watch what happens.

I put a picture to understand better which is the problem.

[image]

**CODE HTML FOR ICONS:**

```
 <td class="gfield_list_icons">   
   <img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms-1/images/blankspace.png" class="add_list_item" title="Add another row" alt="Add a row" onclick="gformAddListItem(this, 10)" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0 3px;">  
   <img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms-1/images/blankspace.png" title="Remove this row" alt="Remove this row" class="delete_list_item" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;" onclick="gformDeleteListItem(this, 10)">
</td>
```

**Code HTML for buton:**

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="gform_button button" value="Envoyer" tabindex="10" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;  ">
```

How can I solve this problem?
Does anyone have any ideas or advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't force height attribute. It is not "natural". You should let your browser decide the heoght and only play with margin and padding attributes in order to get the display you want. Doing this fixed your problem: #gform_fields_1{/* height:280px; */}
#gform_1 > div.gform_body{/* height:280px; */} (Commentes les height sur les deux sélecteurs)

Comment: where I find this file?which is the name?main,css?